# Issue with pipelines on GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I get an error when I'd like to run my pipeline on my `dev` branch.

My file `.gitlab-ci.yml` on my `dev` branch :**

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == /dev/'
      when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Hello World !"
```

First of all, my pipeline is not executed when I create a merge request from `dev` to `master`. And the second issue, I get an error message when I try to execute them with the button "Run pipeline" :

```
Pipeline cannot be run.
No stages / jobs for this pipeline.
```

Comment: Could you just try without slashes ? so `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == dev `

Comment: Without slashes, I get `This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:build:rules:rule if invalid expression syntax`

Comment: Something like: `- if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "dev"`?

Comment: Indeed I forgot double quotes, thanks @Rekovni

Answer (score 1):

Your branch name is `dev` and not macthing the rule you defined. It's why it's Gitlab claims there are no stages/jobs for this pipeline when you execute the run manually.

Please edit the rule to match `dev` like this (double quotes instead of slashes) :

```
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "dev"'
      when: manual
```